# How to use jQuery without making a mess?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I could expect short answers to be "just use AngularJS/Backbone/...(fill the blank)". 
But I believe before I dive into those ultimately, there shall be alternatives and proper ways of getting things done.

So for now, I am using plain html, css, javascript and the only library I use is jQuery and some plugins.

Confession time:
these are the things that I found myself doing all the time and I really think these are "bad" and not "the right thing to do":

1. Use global js variable to hook things together.
    eg.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       window.someVar = ...;
       window.someFun = function(){...};
   });
   ```
2. Need to bind all the event again after DOM manipulation, because it stops working after selecting some elements and putting it somewhere else.
   eg.

   ```
   $(".myElementWithSpecialActionHandler").click(function(){});
   ```

   after the element was relocated, say insert to a different position of the page, the event handler function stops working. So I have to do

   ```
   // after DOM manipulation
   // again >.<
   $(".myElementWithSpecialActionHandler").click(function(){});
   ```
3. Js code is dumped into one giant "main.js" file.
4. css code is dumped into one giant "main.css" file.
5. I use `<tag onClick="someFunction(); ...>` here and there because of issue "2." sometimes.
6. I use inline css here and there.

I am a noob. But I am deeply uneasy writing all these code and yet I am not quite clear how to "make it right". I don't this is an ideal question in SO, but I think this is quite common for new developers. So the answers would benefit a lot of people.

Any enlightenment, web links, pointers to good source, help, and critics are greatly appreciated!

Yours sincerely,
A noob with good taste=> therefore he is disgusted with his own code :(

Comment: Why are you making globals in your point 1? If all your JS is in one "main.js" file can't you just put it all in the document ready handler and use local variables there?

Comment: You might consider breaking this up into distinct answerable questions.  At the moment I believe it should be closed as either "too broad" or "primarily opinion based".

Comment: _"after the element was relocated, say insert to a different position of the page, the event handler function stops working."_ - Moving an element in the page does _not_ unbind its event handler(s), as you can see in a [little demo that I cooked up](http://jsfiddle.net/cyU84/). How are you moving your elements?
The problems you describe don't seem to be about how to use _jQuery_ without making a mess so much as how to use any _JavaScript_ without making a mess.

Comment: @nnnnnn I am using ajax to adding in more element, which cannot access the scope in the first document.ready(). Or do you know better ways ? thanks:)

Comment: @JamesMontagne I would actually agree. But I think all these are "bad things" that a newbie would do, and should be quite obvious for experienced front-end devs.

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles I will break them down. Thanks

Comment: @nnnnnn I did " var content_from_table = from_table_obj.html();
        var content_target_table = to_table_obj.html();" before the ajax call. And I put "from_table_obj.html(content_target_table);
                to_table_obj.html(content_from_table);" in the ajax response handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn basically to swap the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are correct answers to any of these question, but preferences/opinions

1) I don't  like adding variables to global scope, so `window.someVar` is a wrong practice because there can be accidental manipulation of a value by another non relevant scope. If you are using jQuery the need for global variables are very less. If you find yourself using it many times then you may have to rethink about the solution

2) You need to look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead of binding event handler after creating new elements. Assuming you are adding new `input` elements to a div with id `x` then you can do the below in dom ready handler instead of binding it again and again

```
$('#x').on('change', 'input', function(){})
```

3) I normally uses a single js file for my script, so that it can be properly cached

4) same as the script file

5) In string literals I use `'` as the enclosing tag so that I can use `"` inside for html attributes like `var x = '<div class="someclass"></div>'`.

6) I normally wouldn't use inline css, As much as possible try to separate style info from the html markup

Comment: Thanks for the link about event delegation. It's gold!

Answer (score 0):

Just to get it out of the way, you can definitely profit from using some sort of frontend framework. I like jQuery for small things that need to directly manipulate the DOM.

1) some of this is unavoidable. JavaScript is built on global variables. Even Douglas Crockford acknowledges this in "JavaScript: The Good Parts". Just try to keep it to a minimum. Look at patterns to contain things, such as immediately invoked function expressions.

3) Try to find ways to split things up then use something to concatenate and minify it. That said, I'm guilty of bunching things up too much too.

4) There are good reasons to split things out. Your CSS reset can be in its own file. Site-wide layout in another file. Page specific stuff can go into their own files. Templating languages can help you subdivide a page into functional pieces that can have their own CSS files.

5) I didn't know that this was a problem honestly. I've seen plenty of people use single quotes around JS strings.

6) Good for hacking, bad for long term. Just add another class (or id if appropriate). You could put it in a shame.css: http://csswizardry.com/2013/04/shame-css/

Comment: jQuery is not a framework.

Comment: @Rob - Sure it is. "Framework" has several overlapping meaning depending on context. Though having said that I usually call jQuery a "library".

Comment: @nnnn In no way, shape or form is it a framework and frameworks do not have overlapping meaning depending on any context I've ever heard of.

Comment: @RobRibeiro - You may have been responding to my previous comment that I deleted because I realised the OP was trying to include a snippet of html in their point (5) but they didn't use the back-tick ` to quote it so it vanished - I've edited the question to fix that.

Comment: @nnnn Ah, yes, that edit was a little confusion. And I'm with you. Framework denotes something distinctly different than something that is just a library. Libraries are tools to get something done. Frameworks cause you to do things a certain way to accomplish complex sets of tasks more simply. In order to accomplish their goals, frameworks impose structure and limitations. If you want to work outside of that, it is usually at great pain. Libraries lack both the structure and power.

Comment: @Rob - Well an "architecture framework" can sort of overlap with a "software framework" without being exactly the same thing. As for jQuery, it is extensible but the core isn't supposed to be modified, two key points within most definitions of "framework". jQuery doesn't really have "inversion of control", but then in using jQuery you are strongly encouraged to write your code in certain ways though it doesn't force you to. Still, as I already said I would call jQuery a "library", but I don't think it's completely wrong to call it a "framework" when talking informally.